# subquery in IN clause?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables named as

**product_Category**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_category`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `product_category` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `product_category` (`pid`,`cid`) VALUES 
 (1,1),
 (2,3),
 (3,2),
 (4,2),
 (5,3),
 (1,2),
 (2,4),
 (3,1);
```

and **category** table

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mapped_cat_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `category` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`,`cat_name`,`mapped_cat_id`) VALUES 
 (1,'c1','1,2,4'),
 (2,'c2','2,3'),
 (3,'c3','3,4'),
 (4,'c4','4,1,3');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `category` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

When I run this query

```
select distinct pid from
product_category where cid in (1,2,4)
```

I got result of pid (1,3,4,2)

but when I run query

```
select distinct pid from
product_category where cid in (select mapped_cat_id from category where id=1)
```

I got result of pid (1,3)

How to use subquery with 'IN' clause ?

I know my way of asking question is wrong because I dont know how to create table here thats why I wrote query instead of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for  [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) function

```
select distinct pid from
product_category where FIND_IN_SET(cid,
(select mapped_cat_id from category where id=1));
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53737/5)**

Since mapped_cat_id is saved as comma - seperated values(varchar), it is taking only first integer for the condition checking. Here it is 1

Comment: yes this is giving me right answer.Thans!!! can you please tell me what FIND_IN_SET is doing

Comment: check the link for find_in_set in the answer

Answer (score 2):

i think coma separated values are not good. 
Delete contents of your `category` table and use following query to insert

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `cat_name`, `mapped_cat_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'c1', '1'),
    (2, 'c2', '2'),
    (3, 'c3', '3'),
    (4, 'c4', '4'),
    (5, 'c1', '2'),
    (6, 'c1', '4'),
    (7, 'c2', '3'),
    (8, 'c3', '4'),
    (9, 'c4', '1'),
    (10, 'c4', '3');
```

Then use following query to get your result

```
select distinct pid from 
product_category where cid in 
(select mapped_cat_id from category where cat_name='c1')
```

Comment: why it is? in table it is 1,2,4

Comment: I can not change data ... but anyways I got my answer below.